# Kafka Connect - Schema Registry - Unknown magic byte error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I’m quite new to Kafka and after successfully managing some HTTP connectors without schema (“value.converter.schemas.enable”: “false”), I’m struggling to use schemas.

I’ve added the schema (“schemaType”: “JSON”) of my JSON to the schema registry and then modified the configuration of my connector so that it uses it.

```
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://kafka-schemaregistry:8081/",
```

The problem is, I get the (in)famous “Unknown magic byte!”

```
ERROR Error encountered in task test-withschema-0. Executing stage ‘VALUE_CONVERTER’ with class ‘io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter’, where consumed record is {topic=‘mytopic’, partition=0, offset=34, timestamp=1708945734273, timestampType=CreateTime}. (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.LogReporter)
    org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error of topic visitor:
    at io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter.toConnectData(JsonSchemaConverter.java:144)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing JSON message for id -1
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaDeserializer.java:236)

    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: **Unknown magic byte**!
```

I’ve read plenty of posts (including the great How to Fix Unknown Magic Byte Errors in Apache Kafka ) but still struggling to fix it.

I’d have a couple of questions:

I manipulate the JSON in my Kafka topic in order to match what I expect at the other end of the connector via some transformations. The schema should validate the ***resulting ***JSON (after the transformations), is that correct? Or should validate the ***initial ***JSON (before the transformations)?
I currently have only schema in my schema registry, but do I need to somehow tell me connector which schema it should use? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks for any help which can help me better troubleshoot my issue,

Here you can find the schema as I defined it on the schema registry:

curl -https://kafka-schemaregistry:8081/schemas/ | jq

```
[
  {
    "subject": "visitors",
    "version": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "schemaType": "JSON",
    "schema": "{\"$schema\":\"http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#\",\"title\":\"Visitor",\"type\":\"object\",\"properties\":{\"BADGE_PRINT_ENTITY\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_REGISTRATION_STATUS\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_PERSON_ID\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_BUILDING\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_DOC_EXPIRY_DATE\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_EMAIL\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_SITE\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"HOST_FIRST_NAME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_NAME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_DOC_NUMBER\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_APPROVAL_STATUS\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_DOCUMENT_TYPE\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_LAST_NAME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_NATIONALITY\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"HOST_ID\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_DATE_OF_BIRTH\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"PERSONAL_NUMBER\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_TYPE\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"BADGE_NUMBER\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_BADGE_PRINT_STATUS\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_SOCIAL_NAME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"HOST_LAST_NAME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_ORGANISATION\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_ID\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VIST_END_DATE\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISITOR_FIRST_NAME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"HOST_GROUP\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"BADGE_PRINT_DATE_AND_TIME\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"HOST_EMAIL\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_ROOM\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"VISIT_START_DATE\":{\"type\":\"string\"}},\"required\":[\"BADGE_PRINT_ENTITY\",\"VISITOR_REGISTRATION_STATUS\",\"VISITOR_PERSON_ID\",\"VISIT_BUILDING\",\"VISITOR_DOC_EXPIRY_DATE\",\"VISITOR_EMAIL\",\"VISIT_SITE\",\"HOST_FIRST_NAME\",\"VISIT_NAME\",\"VISITOR_DOC_NUMBER\",\"VISITOR_APPROVAL_STATUS\",\"VISITOR_DOCUMENT_TYPE\",\"VISITOR_LAST_NAME\",\"VISITOR_NATIONALITY\",\"HOST_ID\",\"VISITOR_DATE_OF_BIRTH\",\"PERSONAL_NUMBER\",\"VISIT_TYPE\",\"BADGE_NUMBER\",\"VISITOR_BADGE_PRINT_STATUS\",\"VISITOR_SOCIAL_NAME\",\"HOST_LAST_NAME\",\"VISITOR_ORGANISATION\",\"VISIT_ID\",\"VIST_END_DATE\",\"VISITOR_FIRST_NAME\",\"HOST_GROUP\",\"BADGE_PRINT_DATE_AND_TIME\",\"HOST_EMAIL\",\"VISIT_ROOM\",\"VISIT_START_DATE\"]}"
  }
]
```

This is how I tell the connector to use a schema:

```
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://kafka-schemaregistry:8081/",
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It's not possible to convert an existing JSONConverter connector config to JSONSchemaConverter. They are not compatible, and can therefore cause this error since the old JSON events do not contain the "magic byte". More specifically, you cannot "assert a schema" on plain JSON data here; that's not how it works. The data must be produced with a schema to begin with, rather than register a schema after data is produced.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I don't have control on how the initial JSON is being produced, so I need to somehow manage a conversion from schema-less JSON to schema-compliant JSON. Is there a way I can achieve that, possibly without additional tools (like KSql)?

Comment: Ksql/KStreams would copy data to a new topic, so without doing something similar, not that I am aware of